# Pycharm - "package dependencies are not satisfied" - how to find out what package has these requirements?

Tags: python, pycharm

What is the best way to find out what packages are complaining about the requirements not being met?

Everything works fine in my project, but I am guessing that there is a specific one that has the packages in the picture listed in requirements.txt ... I am importing a lot so hoping there is a quick way to scan through them all. (version is Pycharm Pro ...)

[image: pycharm]

Comment: Do you have `requirements.txt` in your project? Try commenting requirements listed there one by one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether a dependency still exists in your project, and find its exact usages, you can run dependency analysis:

From the main menu, select File | Project Structure ⌘; and click Modules | Dependencies.

Right-click the necessary dependency and select Analyze This Dependency.

You can analyze several dependencies one by one without closing the dialog. The result of each analysis will be opened in a separate tab of the Dependency Viewer tool window. After you analyze all necessary dependencies, you can close the Project Structure dialog and view the results.

If it finds no dependency usages in the project, you will be prompted to remove this dependency.

Comment: Thanks for trying to point me in the correct direction. There doesn't seem to be a Modules or Project Dependancies in my Pycharm... I'm on the Linux version which is meant to have a similar menu structure to Windows. Perhaps it's a bug.